# Iterate through csv by column

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of large (~4 million values) csv files, and I need to take each column and create a file that organizes the values in a way that can be interpreted by a different program. The columns are quite different in length (between 2 million and 1000 values), and each csv may have between 4 and 100 columns.

I can load the whole thing into a `pandas.DataFrame` and then iterate through the series, but it's pretty slow:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import os
for f in os.listdir(folder):
    gc = pd.read_csv('{}/{}'.format(folder, f))
    strain = f[:-7] # files have regular name structure, this just gets the name

    with open('{}.txt'.format(strain), 'w+') as out_handle:
        for column in gc:
            series = gc[column]
            for i in range(len(series))[::10]:
                pos = i + 1
                gc_cont = s[i]
                if pd.isnull(gc_cont):
                    continue
                out_handle.write('{} {}'.format(pos, gc_cont) 
                # I'm writing other info, but it's not important here
```

Maybe there's a large performance cost from filling the smaller columns with a million + `NaN` values and loading the whole thing into memory? In any case, I think it would be significantly more efficient to read column by column, but I can't find a way to do that.

Pandas can do `chunk size` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk)), but that's chunking rows. If I write row by row, I'd either have to have 4-100 files open at once, or iterate through the original file that many times to write each separate column. Are either of these approaches appropriate or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the `usecols` option to `read_csv` ? Also, you can consider the `squeeze` option to return a `pandas.Series` which might be faster if you are only working with single columns anyway. Something like

```
cols = ['col0', 'col1', 'col2'] # the columns you want to load
for col in cols:
    data = pandas.read_csv(..., usecols=[col], squeeze=True)
    # format column data etc.
```

Here are the docs

> **usecols** : array-like
>
> > Return a subset of the columns. Results in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.
>
> **squeeze** : boolean, default False
>
> > If the parsed data only contains one column then return a Series

Comment: Only problem here is getting the column names, since they're of variable length. But I guess I only need to read the first line of the csv to do that.

Answer (score 1):

How about reading the whole file into a string and wrapping it in a StringIO  (or BytesIO depending on Python 2/3)?  Then use that as the csv file and iterate once per column.

Something like this:

```
with open('{}/{}'.format(folder, f)) as in_file:
    data = in_file.read()

for index in number_of_columns: # not sure how to derive this
    csv_file = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data))
    for data_row in csv_file:
        # do what you want with data_row[index]
```

EDIT:

It seems this doesn't address the performance problems.  In the light of your comments, I think the best approach for performance is going to be to open all 4 to 100 files at once and write through to them as you read.  I don't think a modern OS will have any problem with that. This is algorithmically the simplest and as a bonus also minimises memory usage.  The work it does in reading and parsing and writing is needed in any version.  There is a possible risk of contention for the disk head I suppose but at a guess I don't think that's going to be a problem.

I think only testing will show if it works faster - it's not obvious.

So that would be something like

```
with open('{}/{}'.format(folder, f)) as in_file:
    csv_file = csv.reader(in_file)

    # open up the files needed and put them into file_list 

    for data_row in csv_file:
        for index,datum in data_row:
            if datum != "":
                file_list[index].write(datum)
```

I haven't exactly emulated your write scheme but I'm sure you get what I mean.  Obviously you'll need a mechanism to find the right number of files (maybe look at the first line?), and close them afterwards etc.

Comment: Am I right that the idea here is to get around the problem of all those `NaN`s being loaded into memory, but we're still loading the whole file into memory yeah?

Comment: yeah that was the idea.  We load it all as a string but we don't build a big table.  But I am not confident it will fix the performance problem since I don't really understand why it's slow.  Rather than experimenting you could try profiling to see where the slow bits are.

Comment: That would require learning profiling, which I haven't done at all (yet... I know I should). It turns out that it's running through the millions of lines hundreds of times that's the problem, not holding it in memory. Your approach has the same problem, since even when I get to columns with no value, there's still a line there. If I load the whole thing into a `DataFrame`, but filter each series to remove `Nan`s before I iterate, it speeds up a lot.

Comment: Not sure - are you saying you think you're OK with your own progress or do you want some more ideas?

Comment: Well, my solution sort of works, but doesn't really answer the question (iterating through a csv by columns). I guess I could add my own answer...

Comment: I don't think you can iterate by columns until you have parsed the data into memory.  So the key thing is going to be to get it into a data structure which then efficiently allows you to iterate by columns.  I'll have a bit more of a think but there may not be much more  to gain.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way may just be to read the entire file into a pandas df and the write each column to their own file.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

for f in os.listdir(folder):
    gc = pd.read_csv('{}/{}'.format(folder, f))
    strain = f[:-7]

    for col in gc.columns:
        temp = gc.col
        temp.to_csv('new_path'+strain+col)
```

This way, even though you have a memory consuming operation you are just splitting up the larger frames into columns and creating their own files that will be easier to work with.